# How can I get the value of children in Firebase database using Javascript?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

How do you get the value of a specific key-value pair in firebase using javascript? I am creating a function for firebase cloud messaging. My function looks like this:

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{receiver_user_id}/{notification_key}').onWrite((event, context)=>{
    const receiver_user_id = context.params.receiver_user_id;
    const notification_key = context.params.notification_key;
    console.log('We have a notification to send to : ', receiver_user_id);
    // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
    const snapshot = event.after.val();
    console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.notification_key, snapshot);
    console.log('original value : ', snapshot);

    if(!event.after.val()){
        console.log('A notification has been deleted: ', notification_key);
        return null;
    }

    const sender_fullname = admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${receiver_user_id}/{notification_key}/notifying_user_fullname`).once('value').toString();
    console.log('full name value : ', sender_fullname);

    const DeviceToken = admin.database().ref(`/tokens/${receiver_user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

        return DeviceToken.then(result=>{
        const token_id = result.val();
        console.log('token id value : ', token_id);

            const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: sender_fullname.toString(),
                body: "You have a new message!",
                icon: "default"
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(response=>{
                console.log('Message has been sent');
            });

        });

});
```

Right now sender_fullname produces [object Promise] in the console log and the notification that is sent. I am uncertain how to get the exact value. An example entry in my realtime database looks like this:

```
original value :  { date_created: '02-21-2020T17:50:32',
  my_id: '0ntpUZDGJnUExiaJpR4OdHSNPkL2',
  notification_key: '-M0dwVL3w1rKyPYbzUtL',
  notification_type: 'liked',
  notifying_user: 'OiBmjJ7yAucbKhKNSHtYHsawwhF2',
  notifying_user_fullname: 'Captain Proton',
  post_key: '-LzSJrOq9Y7hGgoECHRK',
  read: 'false' }
```

Is there any way to get the exact value of say, "notifying_user_fullname"? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of `sender_fullname`, you have to do exactly the way you do for `DeviceToken`!

The [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#once) method returns a promise which resolves with a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot), so you need to use the [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method in order to get the `DataSnapshot` and then, use the [`val()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#val) method.

So the following should do the trick (untested):

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{receiver_user_id}/{notification_key}')
    .onWrite((event, context) => {
        const receiver_user_id = context.params.receiver_user_id;
        const notification_key = context.params.notification_key;
        console.log('We have a notification to send to : ', receiver_user_id);
        // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
        const snapshot = event.after.val();
        console.log('Uppercasing', context.params.notification_key, snapshot);
        console.log('original value : ', snapshot);

        if (!event.after.val()) {
            console.log('A notification has been deleted: ', notification_key);
            return null;
        }

        let sender_fullname;

        return admin.database().ref(`/notifications/${receiver_user_id}/${notification_key}/notifying_user_fullname`).once('value')
            .then(dataSnapshot => {

                sender_fullname = dataSnapshot.val();
                return admin.database().ref(`/tokens/${receiver_user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

            })
            .then(dataSnapshot => {

                const token_id = dataSnapshot.val();
                console.log('token id value : ', token_id);

                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: sender_fullname,
                        body: "You have a new message!",
                        icon: "default"
                    }
                };

                return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload)

            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Message has been sent');
                return null;  // <-- Note the return null here, to indicate to the Cloud Functions platform that the CF is completed
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                return null;
            })

    });
```

---

Note how we chain the different promises returned by the asynchronous methods, in order to return, in the Cloud Function, a Promise, which will indicate to the platform that the Cloud Function work is complete.

I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) which explains the importance of this point.

Comment: That was very helpful, I gave it a try and it worked out perfectly. I hadn't really used Javascript before and the documentation was sometimes a little confusing for me. Thank you for clearing it up and helping me resolve the issue. Also thank you for the video links. Cheers to you.